# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

here is the link to the dataset I used: [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p7OsIq9koVC9gpreNjBiHia4MKh10fP4/view?usp=sharing)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel('enes.xlsx', index='hacim')
X=pd.DataFrame(df['hacim'])
Y=pd.DataFrame(df['delay'])
X

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, Y)

#first print our linear regression for comparison
plt.scatter(X, Y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('X Vs Y')
plt.xlabel('hacim')
plt.ylabel('delay')
plt.show()

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, Y)

X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X, Y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_grid, lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X_grid)), color = 'blue')
plt.title('hacim vs delay)')
plt.xlabel('hacim')
plt.ylabel('delay')
plt.show()
```

When I run the last block of the code in jupyter notebook I get the following error f: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in matplotlib
what is wrong and how can ı fix this problem?

## Error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-59d77fa4cf3d> in <module>
     13 lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, Y)
     14 
---> 15 X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)
     16 X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
     17 plt.scatter(X, Y, color = 'red')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

### Data

```py
,hacim,delay
0,815,1.44
1,750,1.11
2,321,2.37
3,1021,1.44
4,255,1.09
5,564,1.61
6,1455,15.27
7,525,2.7
8,1118,106.98
9,1036,3.47
10,396,1.34
11,1485,21.49
12,1017,12.22
13,1345,2.72
14,312,1.71
15,742,33.79
16,1100,39.62
17,1445,4.88
18,847,1.55
19,991,1.82
20,1296,10.77
21,854,1.81
22,1198,61.9
23,1162,8.22
24,1463,42.25
25,1272,4.31
26,745,2.36
27,521,2.14
28,1247,94.33
29,732,12.55
30,489,1.05
31,1494,12.78
32,591,3.18
33,257,1.18
34,602,4.24
35,335,2.06
36,523,3.63
37,752,7.61
38,349,1.76
39,771,0.79
40,855,39.08
41,948,3.95
42,1378,97.28
43,598,2.69
44,558,1.67
45,634,34.69
46,1146,12.22
47,1087,1.74
48,628,1.03
49,711,3.34
50,1116,7.27
51,748,1.09
52,1212,14.16
53,434,1.42
54,1046,8.25
55,568,1.33
56,894,2.61
57,1041,4.79
58,801,1.84
59,1387,11.5
60,1171,161.21
61,734,2.43
62,1471,17.42
63,461,1.42
64,751,2.36
65,898,2.4
66,593,1.74
67,942,3.39
68,825,1.09
69,715,20.23
70,725,5.43
71,1128,7.57
72,1348,4.49
73,1393,9.77
74,1379,97.76
75,859,2.59
76,612,15.98
77,1495,8.22
78,887,1.85
79,867,38.65
80,1353,1.6
81,851,60.25
82,1079,24.05
83,1100,25.58
84,638,1.23
85,1115,1.94
86,1443,4.79
87,1421,10.33
88,1279,7.29
89,1176,173.44
90,315,1.53
91,1019,34.03
92,1337,48.67
93,576,28.83
94,919,2.88
95,361,1.5
96,989,1.47
97,1286,32.11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
X_grid = np.arange(X.min()[0], X.max()[0], 0.1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Scott, thank you very much for answering both of my questions today.